# Position label text 10px right of the background-image

Tags: css

I have a label that has a background image and some text. I need to position the text 10px right of the background image, such that the background image is clearly visible.

I need to do this without adding additional HTML elements or Javascript.

Here's the source code I have so far:

```css
label {
  background-image: url('http://missouri.municipalbonds.com/img/icons/add.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<label>This is my label</label>
```

Any ideas on which CSS property I am missing to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but `padding-left: 10px;` should do it

Answer (score 6):

Image is `16px` wide, `10px` to the right of it is a total of `26px`.

Use `padding` or `padding-left` for the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/L0ctetdg/

```css
label{
  background-image: url('http://missouri.municipalbonds.com/img/icons/add.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
    
  padding-left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<label>This is my label</label>
```

---

It must also be said that this is seriously basic stuff. Before you come running to StackOverflow on the first problem you encounter, try treating the language with a little respect by studying it properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

http://hashcss.com/schools/